# When should we create new modules?

Tags: php, search, module

I have:

- `User` module
- `Items` module
- `Payment` module

Now I want to have a search function to search for items.

Should I create a search module or make a function search in `Items` modules?

Comment: Is search itself generic enough to search anything or do you have a specific search for each type of thing?

Comment: search for anything. Like a advanced search

Comment: It's really hard to say without seeing your codebase and. Even then this is primarily opinion based. Personally, I'd split the searches up and have one global search component if necessary.